# Is there a JavaScript / HTML5 code that can convert any video format to mp4 format, and then upload it to a storage server for viewing on any client?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, video

JavaScript / HTML5 code to convert any video format to mp4 format and upload to my video storage server(e.g. amazon S3) so that it can be later downloaded and played in mp4 format on my web/android/ios client.
I know there are libraries to convert any video format to mp4 format on server side, however if I have to use any such library then I need to first upload the video to my application server, convert it to mp4 format and then upload to my video storage server(e.g. Amazon S3). I do not want this intermediate hop where video data is moved from client side to my application server and then to the video storage server.
Kindly suggest a suitable option.

Comment: using javascript for transcoding (especially "any format") is really not a practical solution. Server-side processing (or using a service such as Azure Media Services, AWS Elastic Transcode, Zencoder or one of the FFMPG servers rather than hosting your own) will be more reliable, scalable and give a much better user experience

Answer (score 1):

As Offbeatmammal says in the comments, its hard to see (today) a practical way to do the video conversion in the browser as the processing required is really quite high.

If you do want to experiment there is a project which has built FFMPEG into a JavaScript library which can be used in a browser:

- https://github.com/bgrins/videoconverter.js

I'm not sure how actively this is being maintained as the most recent updates are quite old and it is, unsurprisingly, slow but there is a demo you can play around with to get a feel for it.